# MMP Geodesic algorithm I need clarification

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, geometry, triangulation

I am reading the 1987 paper on Geodesics on polyhedra and I am confused on something.

The paper states:

> If $I1==NIL$, the channel is simply that part of $f’$ to the left of $\beta_2c_2$; and if
> $I2==NIL$, the channel is that to the right of $\beta_1c_1$.

"Right" and "left" are pretty meaningless terms. So far I have at least 3 interpretations of the areas they mean:

Orthogonal projection onto the opposite edge:

[image]

Angular projection based on some angular parameter:
[image]

Or the entire face.

All of these can be thought of as "the left" of the red segment. Which one is the one the authors meant?

Comment: I skimmed the paper, and it wasn't clear to me either. On a side note, this is something you might be interested in: From "Fast Exact and Approximate Geodesics on Meshes": "Unfortunately, as far as we know the MMP algorithm has not been implemented previously and thus has not made its way into practice.".

Comment: Well that paper implemented it, and as far as I know there are 2 open source implementations of the algorithm, one seems to be based on the other:
Here's one:
https://github.com/mojocorp/geodesic